# Aurelia bundle not found

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

I am set the project in my local mac, and i want to run it with "gulp watch", i do it before and its work fine for me but now when i do "gulp watch" and go to browser i got an error by browser.

**GET http://localhost:9001/dist/aurelia-bundle-8d7cabedaf.js 404 (Not Found)**

I already tried to do

1. delete the node_modules folder.
2. delete nodejs globally and reinstall him again.
3. reinstall node_modules and jspm_packges.
4. change nodejs versions to 6/8.
5. reinstall gulp and jspm.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start server.js",
    "stop": "pm2 stop server.js",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "e2e": "gulp serve webdriver-standalone e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.9.0",
    "express": "^4.13.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jspm": "^0.16.45",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "sitemap-generator": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aurelia-bundler": "^0.3.0",
    "aurelia-tools": "^0.1.18",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-flow": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-loose": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.10.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.2.0",
    "conventional-changelog": "0.0.11",
    "del": "^1.1.0",
    "express-sitemap": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-bump": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.1.3",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-browserify": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-ngannotate-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "object.assign": "^1.0.3",
    "require-dir": "0.3.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "vinyl-paths": "^1.0.0",
    "yargs": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-configuration": "github:vheissu/aurelia-configuration@^1.0.4",
      "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.5",
      "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.1",
      "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.1",
      "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-history": "npm:aurelia-history@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-history-browser": "npm:aurelia-history-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-http-client": "npm:aurelia-http-client@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-i18n": "npm:aurelia-i18n@^0.5.3",
      "aurelia-loader-default": "npm:aurelia-loader-default@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.2",
      "aurelia-logging": "npm:aurelia-logging@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.0",
      "aurelia-logging-console": "npm:aurelia-logging-console@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-metadata": "npm:aurelia-metadata@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.4",
      "aurelia-path": "npm:aurelia-path@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.1",
      "aurelia-polyfills": "npm:aurelia-polyfills@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.3",
      "aurelia-route-recognizer": "npm:aurelia-route-recognizer@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-task-queue": "npm:aurelia-task-queue@^1.0.0-beta.1.2.1",
      "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "aurelia-templating-resources": "npm:aurelia-templating-resources@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.3",
      "aurelia-templating-router": "npm:aurelia-templating-router@^1.0.0-beta.1.1.2",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.5",
      "fetch": "github:github/fetch@^0.11.0",
      "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@^4.5.0",
      "framework7": "npm:framework7@^1.4.2",
      "geea-develop/aurelia-tag-manager-plugin": "github:geea-develop/aurelia-tag-manager-plugin@^1.0.9",
      "geea-develop/bootstrap-datetimepicker": "github:geea-develop/bootstrap-datetimepicker@^5.0.0",
      "google-maps-api": "npm:google-maps-api@^2.0.1",
      "i18next-xhr-backend": "npm:i18next-xhr-backend@^0.6.0",
      "isomorphic-fetch": "npm:isomorphic-fetch@^2.2.1",
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.1.4",
      "lightbox2": "npm:lightbox2@^2.9.0",
      "moment": "npm:moment@2.8.4",
      "numeral": "npm:numeral@1.5.3",
      "photoswipe": "npm:photoswipe@^4.1.1",
      "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.3",
      "toastr": "npm:toastr@^2.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to see the site without bundle errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your dist directory if it contains the file?

Comment: The dist folder does not contain this file when I do "gulp watch",
but if I do "gulp bundle" the file exists.

Comment: Are you sure the port is 9001?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have the solution to this problem,

1. command "jspm unbundle" this command clean every build of the project.
2. and command "jspm install aurelia-history-browser" update the browser.